# How to resolve TCPSERVERWRAP while running tests in Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I was running integrations tests for my app using jest. It seemed to work fine, but when I ran it again I kept getting an error.

Here is a shortened version of the error...

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

● TCPSERVERWRAP

  10 | const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  11 |
> 12 | module.exports = app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`Listening on port ${port}`))
     |                      ^
  13 |

  at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:12:22)


ReferenceError: You are trying to import a file after the Jest environment is torn down.
    at (Stack trace here)


D:\Ethan\Coding\Node\vidly\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at (Stack trace here)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details
```

It's strange because all my tests have passed but it still throws the error. I have 2 integration tests and 1 unit test in my app.

Here is a shortened version of one of my integration tests...

```
const request = require('supertest')

const { User } = require('../../../models/user')

let server

describe('auth', () => {
  let token

  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require('../../../index')
    token = new User().generateAuthToken()
  })
  
  afterEach(() => server.close())


  const exec = () => {
    return request(server).get('/api/users/me').set('x-auth-token', token)
  }

  it('should return 401 if no token is provided', () => {
    token = ''

    exec().then(res => expect(res.status).toBe(401))
  })
})
```

It seems to point to the server I've exported from my main index.js file. Any help, please?

Comment: Don't import a file that contains `listen` in tests, separate its call to another file if needed. This is unwanted with supertest.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I posted about this before cannot find a relevant answer. Basically you need to have `app = express();` and so on in app.js, and `app.listen(...)` in index.js, and import `app` from app.js and not index.js in tests.

Answer (score 2):

To run Jest with ExpressJS you can pass the express app object to Supertest which runs listen. That way it can set the port, do the cleanup, and you don't have to do any of that yourself.

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../src/app");

describe("Test the root path", () => {
  test("It should response the GET method", () => {
    return request(app)
      .get("/")
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

References:
[How To Guide](https://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/)